# Google Data Studio: Filter report data through parameter in URL

Tags: looker-studio

I have a Google sheet where each row contains data for a single person.
First column is an alphanumeric random id.

Is there any way I can build a personal score card report which I can share with each person through a link?

The link would contain a parameter for filtering the datasource by the id column. I mean sharing by sending links via email, for example:

```
Send an email to John with the following link: <url>?id=kfdjfhdfljdshfsdkj
Send an email to Mark with the following link: <url>?id=fdyfdhfsfjsdkjfksd ….
```

I have thought about adding a filter control plus enabling bookmark urls, but would like to avoid that as that would be a possible security breach. Other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your data in BigQuery, an alternative approach is to use authorised views. It is explained in details in [How To Control Access To BigQuery At Row Level With Groups](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-control-access-to-bigquery-at-row-level-with-groups-1cbccb111d9e)

Comment: Yes, but then people would need to validate themselves and also (dón't remember precesiely) I would need to seup one group permission per user, which is not good for the use case. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The [filter based on the email address](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766) feature can be implemented by adding an `email` address field alongside the existing field(s), such as `alphanumeric random id` in the Google Sheet.

Once that's done, connect the [Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6295223) Data Source to Google Data Studio, and then at the Data Source,  [filter based on the email address](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766) of the respective user ID (filter located on the upper left of the Data Source section).